# How can I convert from qi::double_ to string?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, type-conversion, boost-spirit-qi

I am using `spiri::qi` to parse a text and pushing what I parse into a `vector<string>`, for the most part its fine since they are mostly names and addresses, but there are also some numbers that I am parsing with `double_`, but once I push it to the `vector` it considers it a character code, like `'\x3'` in lieu of `3.0`. I don’t want to make use of `variant` since its too much work for just a few cases. Is there anyway I can convert the result of `double_`  to `string` before pushing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `raw[double_]` (or even more exactly `as_string[raw[double_]]`).

The first works like any rule that has *attribute compatibility with a container of characters*. The latter atomically exposes a `std::string` (there's one for `std::wstring` as well).

**BONUS**

To complete Jonathan Mee's suggestion to "just use the language" (paraphrasing... :)) you *can*, see the last demo grammar below:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c3a3dc73fd90557)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

int main() {

    using It = std::string::const_iterator;
    auto to_string_f = [](auto v) { return std::to_string(v); };
    px::function<decltype(to_string_f)> to_string_ { to_string_f };

    for (std::string const input : { "3.14", "+inf", "NaN", "-INF", "99e-3" })
    {
        for (auto const& grammar : std::vector<qi::rule<It, std::string()>> {
                //qi::double_,  // results in strange binary interpretations, indeed
                qi::raw[ qi::double_ ], 
                qi::as_string [ qi::raw[ qi::double_ ] ], 
                qi::double_ [ qi::_val = to_string_(qi::_1) ], 
            })
        {
            auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
            std::string result;
            if (qi::parse(f, l, grammar, result))
                std::cout << input << "\t->\t" << result << "\n";
            else
                std::cout << "FAILED for '" << input << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Printing

```
3.14    ->  3.14
3.14    ->  3.14
3.14    ->  3.140000
+inf    ->  +inf
+inf    ->  +inf
+inf    ->  inf
NaN ->  NaN
NaN ->  NaN
NaN ->  nan
-INF    ->  -INF
-INF    ->  -INF
-INF    ->  -inf
99e-3   ->  99e-3
99e-3   ->  99e-3
99e-3   ->  0.099000
```

Note that `std::to_string` doesn't result in the literal input, so it might not roundtrip faithfully for your purposes.

Comment: Added a demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c3a3dc73fd90557)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just:

> Anyway I can convert the result of `double_` to `string` before pushing it?

Then yeah you can convert any number back into a `string` using [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: That's not really answering the question in context, since I bet you can't show how to use `to_string` from within a Qi grammar rule.

Comment: @sehe I had taken the phrase "the result of `double_` to `string`" to mean that he had already extracted the value into a variable. But I've given you a +1 cause you're right, doing it directly in the grammar vastly simplifies the problem.

Comment: Just completed a sample that also shows how `std::to_string` could in fact be used (not though that doing that might loose some information from the input, because the representation will be whatever `std::to_string` chooses, not the actual input).

Comment: @sehe Nice I'd give you another +1 but, you've already got mine :)